# wordpress use gettext library for translating pages content

Tags: wordpress, gettext, multilingual

Im using wordpress to build a multilanguage website.I know exist many multilanguage plugins for this purpose.But I don't want to do in this way.There's any work around? could I use gettext library instead of plugins to translate pages content?

thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - NO

Slightly more long: gettext shows **previously prepared** translation (if exist) of piece of text, stored in mo-files. For user-generated content you just haven't this translation and methods of getting strings for translation

Note: all above is true, if *multilanguage website* for you means site with multilanguage content (and changeable from language to language), not  just with different languages of interface